# WEB 2.0 приложение, как правильно организовать работу?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Доброе утро, господа! Есть небольшой проект - имеется  некое кол-во скриптов на PS, они выполняют требуемое действие и записывают результат в базу(MS SQL), далее при помощи php эти данный берутся из базы и раскидываются по таблицам(HTML). Проект так же использует Jquery UI. Суть вопроса - хочется сделать приятный интерфейс с добавлением отслеживаемых скриптов и удалением уже имеющихся таблиц(нажал на крестик рядом с именем таблицы, таблица удалилась). Как правильно организовать такой функционал?

P.S. не сочтите за рекламу, исходники можете посмотреть тут https://github.com/Vankalif/script_mon

Comment: Я так понял, что таблицы эти обображают какие-то записи из БД. А что должно стать с той таблицей, которую вы удаляете (нажав на крестик)? Данный должны удалить из БД? Или таблицы должна быть скрыта на время. Или что? Разъясните всё как следует, пожалуйста.

Comment: Она должна полностью удалиться

Comment: вы меня не слышите. Что значит полностью удалиться? Что именно Вы подразумеваете, когда говорите такое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вашим исходникам, вопрос больше в том как оперировать данными между файлами проекта.В файле data_loader.php опишите классы (или тупо найдите, в инете их очень до краёв) работы с базой. Они должны только возвращать результат выборки из бд массивом. Следующий файл, например, view.php должен подключать классы первого файла, и циклом заполнять таблицы данными. Как подключать, создавать объект и выводить foreach-ом, думаю, объяснять не надо. 
В случае с удалением: на кнопки навешиваете обработчики, и через них обращаетесь к классу в data_loader.php, тот делает что вы хотите - удаляет из базы, например. В общем так, на примитивном уровне.
Можете и без классов реализовать, в одном файле, с чередой проверок пост-гет и бесконечным листингом. Но оно не по-пацански.

Comment: вы молодец, спасибо вам за совет, если у вас есть желание можем более плотно пообщаться по проекту. Еще раз спасибо!